# React native Android image no t saving in api using post

Tags: reactjs, react-native

...
react native  image not uploading in post data through api .
im getting error image is not in form data format
...

... this is my coding how to upload image to api.ialso try using formdata but it getting error 'data no save'

...

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import { useState } from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Emergencycont = ({ route, navigation }) => {



    const
        {
            language, imagefront, imageback,
        } = route.params

   const [_idpic1, set_idpic1]=useState(imagefront);
    const [_idpic2, set_idpic2]=useState(imageback);
const [_lan, set_lang] = useState(language);


  const laterBtnPress = async () => {

         //for facebook login

        let url = val === "google" ? "https://YOUR API LINK" :
       
       
        const data = {
            _lan, _idpic1,_idpic2,
        }
        axios.post(url, data)
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        navigation.navigate('Zapping')
    };
```

....
i try many to save image but it not saving in api
i try through formdata also but not saving in android but working in ios its saving data in ios.
how to save image in api

Answer (score 0):

Hello as per my understanding of your given code you have to make Form Data of both of your images to make API call like below

```
const form = new FormData();
const imageFileData1 = {
    name: "File Name",
    type: "File Type",
    uri: "File URI",
  };

const imageFileData2 = {
    name: "File Name",
    type: "File Type",
    uri: "File URI",
  };

form.append('_lan', JSON.stringify(lan));
form.append('_idpic1', imageFileData1);
form.append('_idpic2', imageFileData2);
```

**Now Your code api calling function is looks like this**

```
const laterBtnPress = async () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    const imageFileData1 = {
      name: "File Name",
      type: "File Type",
      uri: "File URI",
    };
    const imageFileData2 = {
      name: "File Name",
      type: "File Type",
      uri: "File URI",
    };
    data.append('_lan', JSON.stringify(lan));
    data.append('_idpic1', imageFileData1);
    data.append('_idpic2', imageFileData2);
    let url = val === "google" ? "https://YOUR API LINK" :
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    navigation.navigate('Zapping')
  };
```